# How kotlin multiplatform call function on native module in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to move JS logic to KMM but I want to reuse Native Library like react-native-async-storage. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a NPM module, then you should be able to use NPM libraries in Kotlin/JS.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/using-packages-from-npm.html

Note that you would need to write external declarations. You can write it  manually or use [Dukat](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-external-declarations-with-dukat.html) tool